# How to fetch Json data in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have JSON response from angular front end. the response is:

```
 {
  "selected": null,
  "lists": [
    {
      "board one": [
        {
          "card_name": "Card 10",
          "id": 1,
          "card_unique_id": "PC1"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "card 11",
          "id": 2,
          "card_unique_id": "PC2"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "card12",
          "id": 3,
          "card_unique_id": "PC3"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "adfaf",
          "id": 12,
          "card_unique_id": "PC12"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "fa df af ad",
          "id": 13,
          "card_unique_id": "PC13"
        }
      ],
      "BoardId": "PB1"
    },
    {
      "board two": [
        {
          "card_name": "Card 20",
          "id": 4,
          "card_unique_id": "PC4"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "CArd 21",
          "id": 5,
          "card_unique_id": "PC5"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "card 23",
          "id": 6,
          "card_unique_id": "PC6"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "Card 24",
          "id": 7,
          "card_unique_id": "PC7"
        }
      ],
      "BoardId": "PB2"
    },
    {
      "board three": [
        {
          "card_name": "Card 30",
          "id": 8,
          "card_unique_id": "PC8"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "card 31",
          "id": 9,
          "card_unique_id": "PC9"
        },
        {
          "card_name": "card 32",
          "id": 10,
          "card_unique_id": "PC10"
        }
      ],
      "BoardId": "PB3"
    },
    {
      "new board": [
        {
          "card_name": "card 40",
          "id": 11,
          "card_unique_id": "PC11"
        }
      ],
      "BoardId": "PB4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to fetch all card name in laravel. In laravel controller function i code like this: It returns some error. I dont know how to fetch all these `card_names`.

```
    public function sortupdate(Request $response)
    {
       $get_result_arr = json_decode($response->getContent());

       foreach($get_result_arr as $result){
           $lists = $result->lists;
       }
     }
```

please anyone help.
Thanks Advanced..

Comment: Please be more specific on the error it returns

Comment: i didn't know how to fetch. please answer. Thanks Wistar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `true` to `json_decode()` to get an associative array:

```
$get_result_arr = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
```

Then iterate over this array and get each `card_name`:

```
foreach ($get_result_arr['lists'] as $list) {
    foreach (array_values($list)[0] as $card) {
        echo $card['card_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey Mezenin. But it returns Undefined index: lists.

Comment: $get_result_arr returns array. but return error as undefined index lists

Comment: @SARAN, I've updated the code and tested it. It works perfectly with your data.