# How to traverse through this JSON data?

Tags: php, html, laravel, sugarcrm

I'm working on Laravel and Sugar REST API in order to login, fetch data from the leads module and display onto my custom HTML page in a table. So far I have been able to extract the data required in JSON format, but I do not understand how to traverse it so that I can have relevant data inserted into the HTML table. I have tried to test the print through the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Login Application </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/main/successlogin')}}">Hello User!</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Leads</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>

@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('leadsdata'))
<div>
    <pre>
       {{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('leadsdata')}}
    </pre>
</div>

@endif


</body>
</html>
```

This is the result that I get:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbViE.png)

There are 2 issues with this:

1. the data in `{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('leadsdata')}}` is not decoded. When I apply `json_decode` and then run this same script it gives me **htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**, so I can't work with the object without having to exclusively write `print_r` on it.
2. I want to only traverse the **records** field in the object, and pick out specific fields eg. name, assigned-to etc. for adding to the table.

How do I achieve this? I know this may seem to be a mediocre question but I can't seem to have this sorted out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch Json data in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380272/how-to-fetch-json-data-in-laravel)

Comment: Note: you can simply use {{ Session::get('leadsdata') }}.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile How in the world is this a duplicate of a Laravel issue ?! SugarCRM is not using Laravel.

Comment: @Hamzaouiii please read the question carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can directly use it by "->" in the blade means you can directory use object 
  `$data->records` and traverse in `foreach` in blade.
- why you want to json_decode.

Eg.

`@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('leadsdata'))
       @foreach((\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('leadsdata'))->results as $leadsdata)
          {{ $leadsdata->name }}
       @endforeach
@endif`

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: hello @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin
can you please check the example. Thank you.